# RAILS_ENV=production rails assets:precompile - ruby_racer_runtime.rb:73: Segmentation fault

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

It return the following error when i run RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile --trace

** Execute assets:precompile
.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@rails5/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:73: [BUG] Segmentation fault at 0x00000000000018
ruby 2.4.1p111 (2017-03-22 revision 58053) [x86_64-linux]

The following are the environment details

ruby version : ruby-2.4.1
Rails Version: 5.1.7
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic

My Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.7'
gem 'execjs'
gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby
gem 'mysql2'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

After I install ruby 2.5.5. The below is my Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.3'
gem 'mysql2'
gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'chromedriver-helper'
end

gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Comment: Ruby `2.4.1` is a bit outdated and already got several minor updates. The latest `2.4` version is currently `2.4.6`. Although support for Ruby `2.4.6` will end soon too, is it an option to update to at least that version?

Comment: I have installed ruby 2.5.5 but I still got the error .rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5@rails5/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:73: [BUG] Segmentation fault at 0x0000000000000018
ruby 2.5.5p157 (2019-03-15 revision 67260) [x86_64-linux]

Comment: Mabye I am totally wrong, but there are a lot of issues like this in the [issue list](https://github.com/cowboyd/therubyracer/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+segmentation+) for therubyracer. Can't you just switch to one of the other supported runtimes like Node.js or one of the others listed [here](https://github.com/rails/execjs)?